# Wait until any key is held in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-elcapitan

I have an AppleScript background script which generates hotkey events by `System Events`. So I need stop the script before generate keystroke and wait until user releases all keys (otherwise effect will be unpredictable).

How can I get this done?
I don't need exactly AppleScript solution. It does not matter, I can just call external Python/Bash/ObjC/Swift. Anything, but I only very dislike to run obscure and untrusted binaries.

Comment: Do you also want to prevent the user from doing anything while your script is pressing the keys?

Comment: @Willeke no, I just want script to wait safe moment and then generate a keystroke.

Comment: Applescript is not great at what I think you're asking. Can you not post code so we understand what you're really talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any key, but you can wait for modifier keys to be released.

eg. don't continue until user releases option and shift keys

```
use framework "AppKit"

property NSShiftKeyMask : a reference to 131072
property NSAlternateKeyMask : a reference to 524288
property NSEvent : a reference to current application's NSEvent

set modifier_down to true
repeat while modifier_down
    set modifier_flags to NSEvent's modifierFlags()
    set option_down to ((modifier_flags div (get NSAlternateKeyMask)) mod 2) = 1
    set shift_down to ((modifier_flags div (get NSShiftKeyMask)) mod 2) = 1
    set modifier_down to option_down or shift_down
end repeat
```

and here are keycodes for the other modifiers

```
property NSCapsLockMask : a reference to 65536
property NSControlKeyMask : a reference to 262144
property NSCommandKeyMask : a reference to 1048576
property NSFunctionKeyMask : a reference to 8388608
```